# Can i read Redirect location?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, iframe

I have the following webiste which redirects to a particular resource:

`foo.com` -> `abc.com`

foo.com has NO X-frame header , thus can be iframed
abc.com HAS X-frame header, thus it can't be iframed.

I just wanted to get at any cost the response location header (that is where it will redirect) which is caused by this url.

```
foo.com/redirect.com
```

The response contains a location header which redirects.

Is there's any means to see where uts redirecting?

**Attempted**

I tried to read iframe using `this.src` location but it returned only foo.com (that is initial url) not the `abc.com`.

I tried reading Chrome console but failed.

I tried

```
var ifrm = $('iframe');
var iurl = ifrm.window.location;
```

Any other way?

Thanks

Here's what i want:

i add this html tag

```
<iframe src="http://foo.com"></iframe>
```

Now ALWAYS `foo.com` will redirect to `abc.com`. So how do my iframe will knows that

> Oh! foo.com has redirected me to abc.com!, now javascript, alert user that iframe is redirecting!

Basically: How do i know where an iframe is redirecting me?

Comment: You do it by this way: `var ifrm = $('iframe');`
`var iurl = ifrm.window.location;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefineds @ (index):27`

Comment: It doesn't read new location , just shows old location

Comment: You can use `location.href`.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Returns foo.com not abc.com

Comment: Can you update in the question, what have you done so far and what have you got, and what you would like to get? I'll reopen the question!

Comment: What have you attempted? I can see that you are explaining the scenario!